# How can i get data back from this dialog fragment in this code?

Tags: android, list, callback, dialog, fragment

I have tried, but doesn't work. Let me show more details ok?

I have this on my activity:

mainActivity

```
xTipo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        new ListTipo().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"ListTipo");
    }
});
```

And i have this java code to my DialogFragment

Dialog Fragment:

```
public class ListTipo extends DialogFragment {
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
    
            int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
            theme = R.style.dTheme;
            setStyle(style, theme);
            String [] tipos = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tipo_atendimento);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), theme);
            builder.setTitle("\b\b\bTipo de Atendimento");
            builder.setItems(tipos, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

This work fine, but I can't pick up the result.
Thank you for your time and patient!

Comment: share your code, what is xTipo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a callback interface, implement it on your code (where you set up the listeners), then pass it as a parameter in the dialog.

Example:

```
public interface Callback {
    void onResult(Object result);
}
```

```
private Callback callback;
public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
    this.callback=callback;
}

// where you want to pass the result
if(callback!=null)
    callback.onResult(YOUR_RESULT);
```

Where you create the dialog:

```
xTipo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ListTiop fragment=new ListTipo();
        fragment.setCallback(result -> {
            // run your code with the result
        });
        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"ListTipo");
    }
});
```

Comment: What kind of Callback I need to import?

Comment: The one you created using the first code block

Comment: thank you. It's work

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Passing arguments in fragment constructor could lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: @ElnatanDerech changed the code a bit