# I want to pass date data to another fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, parcelable

I want to use DateDialogFragment and put the date I get there to another fragment

How do I put the set date after getting the calendar instance?

```
class DateDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        return DatePickerDialog(requireActivity(), this, year, month, dayOfMonth)
    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

        val selectedDate = calendar.time
        val selectedDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.JAPAN).format(calendar.time)

        val bundle = Bundle()

        bundle.putString("SELECTED_DATE", selectedDateFormat)
        bundle.putParcelable("SELECTED_DATE_PARCELABLE", selectedDate)

        setFragmentResult("REQUEST_KEY", bundle)
    }

}
```

I found something called parcelable, but I don't know how to use it!

I tried to use the Long type to handle dates, but the database could not handle data comparison, so I tried to use SQLite's Parcelable.

Comment: Maybe this can be useful.https://stackoverflow.com/a/70859352/20839582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data between fragments as an argument:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data?authuser=1

Or another option:
[How to pass values between Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)